# $\dim B/A=\dim B-\dim A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $A,B$ are two vector spaces over $k$ such that $B\subseteq A$, can I say $\dim B/A=\dim B-\dim A$? I need of this result to prove a theorem I'm working on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yup. Except if both have dim $\infty$ in which case you can't really say that.

Comment: If both $A,B$ are  of finite dimension, this equation is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to consider the basis. If you have a basis for $A$, you can always extend it to a basis of $B$. The extended vectors, when mapped to $B/A$ via the natural projection $B\to B/A$, becomes a basis for $B/A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

For general vector spaces $A,B$ with $B\subset A$ we usually define $\text{codim}(B)=\text{dim}(A/B)$. It then holds that $$\text{dim}A=\text{dim}B+\text{codim}B$$ When infinite dimensions are involved it may become impossible to subtract $\text{dim}B$ from both sides.

Comment: I didn't know we define $\text{codim} (B)=\dim(A/B)$, thank you for point me this out.